# Creating decreasing sequence with (x++)%n in C#

Tags: c#, modulus, sequences

So, I know that with a code snippet such as:

```
int x = 0; //class field variable

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text += (x++)%4 + 1;
}
```

a sequence of 12341234 is displayed on the form if the button is clicked 8 times.

**My goal is to get 43214321 to display.**

I'm able to get 32103210 with:

```
int x = 0; //class field variable

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text += 3-(x++)%4;
}
```

I'm also able to get 32143214 with:

```
int x = 1; //class field variable

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text += 4-(x++)%4 + ;
}
```

**What am I doing wrong? And is there a general formula for this?**

**Note:** My x DOES have to be initialized to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula:
`5-(1+(x+++3)%4)`

That is:

```
Label1.Text += (5-(1+(x+++3)%4)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the formula to:
`Label1.Text += 4-((x-1)++)%4;`

Answer (score 0):

The first line of code that you've written is basically cycling between 3 to 1.

```
 x=0;      
 Label1.Text += 3-(x++)%4;
```

x=0 || Output=3.
*Label1.Text=* 0+3-(0%4)=**3**
x=1 || Output=2.
*Label1.Text=* 0+3-(1%4)=**2**
x=2 || Output=1.
(Dry run as done above)
x=3 || Output=0.
(dry run as done above)
x=4 and the cycle repeats.

You could dry run your second line of code to understand why your answer comes the way it does, but to answer your question in concise:

```
 int x = 0; //class field variable
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
            Label1.Text += 4-(x++)%4;
     }
```